# Почему у записей свои хлебные крошки?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть участок кода, который выводит хлебные крошки на странице, все прекрасно когда это страница и у нее есть родитель, но когда дело доходит до записи (в моем случае это какая-то новость), когда я нажимаю на кнопку перехода, то цепочка хлебных крошек нарушается и последовательность начинается с главной страницы.
Код, который отвечает за вывод хлебных крошек:

```
<ul class="bread-crumbs flex">

    <li class="bread-crumbs__el"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>

    <?php if($parent = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID())): ?>

        <li class="bread-crumbs__el"><a href="<?=get_the_permalink($parent)?>"><?=get_the_title($parent)?></a></li>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <li class="bread-crumbs__el"><?=get_the_title()?></li>

</ul>
```

Кто может подсказать куда капать? Начал недавно изучать wp и плохо понимаю как он работает.

Comment: Потому что в WordPress есть два типа постов: иерархический (это страницы) и не-иерархический (это записи). Ваш код работать для записей не будет просто потому, что он использует `wp_get_post_parent_id()`. Вы чего хотите добиться-то для записей?

Comment: Что бы когда я к примеру заходил на страницу где у меня выводятся все мои новости на сайте (На данный момент цепочка хлебных крошек не нарушена), когда я нажимаю на новость, то цепочка прерывается и у меня начинается цепочка от главной страницы. Когда я был на странице с новостями, у меня была следующая цепочка: Главная - Новости. Когда я перешел непосредственно в новость, у меня должна быть цепочка: Главная - Новости - Новость, но она прерывается и выводится: Главная - Новость.

Comment: Есть какой-то способ сохранить родителя как "Новости" для записей (Новость)?

Comment: Изменить код так, чтобы в случае обработки поста в качестве родителя выводилась его категория.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_541/samyie-hlebnyie-kroshki-breabcrumbs-dlya-wordpress.html